# Button with text below icon (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I am trying to create a button, like this one: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf6bE.png).
I have just tried to make simple button and use the attribute `android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_my_icon`, but in this way i can't change the size of the icon :(

In my project I use databinding and constraint layout, and in this fragment I must use more than 5 similar buttons like that. The better way that I have found is the using a MaterialCardView with inner RelativeLayout.

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/cardTranslationTraining"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/cardSize"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/cardSize"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@drawable/card_color_selector">  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="60sp"
            android:layout_height="60sp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Translate" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

But there are more than 200 strings and it look awful!

How could I make it without using big nesting? Could anybody help?
Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

Try below code in layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="#DDDDDD">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    android:translationZ="2dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_like"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Like"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is ouput od code is:

[image]

I hope it is work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `custom view component` and use the same layout for a single time. And place your custom view into the xml layout like below. Also You can set **custom attributes** like button image source and text

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customviews"> 

    <com.example.customviews.YourCustomView
     custom:showText="true"
     custom:labelPosition="left" /> 

    <com.example.customviews.YourCustomView
     custom:showText="true"
     custom:labelPosition="left" /> 

    <com.example.customviews.YourCustomView
     custom:showText="true"
     custom:labelPosition="left" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

[Custom View Component Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components)

[Custom View Class](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view)

Comment: Cool idea and everythig works correct, but now I've got the problem with click on the cuttom view :( I just want to start doing method in ViewModel:   `<com.presentation.utils.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/cardSize"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/cardSize"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onClick()}"
            app:image="@drawable/ic_translate"
            app:text="@string/translate" />`

Comment: But it has never called. What can be the problem?

Comment: @lst11 you can write an interface/callback which works as an onClickListener. And set the listeners inside your activity/fragment. There are multiple ways to do it. Never tried custom view onClick via data binding before. May be you are missing something different.